# Will loading data asynchronously speed up page load?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, authentication

On my current webpage I load the table content from a mysql db with php. But the db contains about 1500+ rows and they are all encrypted. So it takes about 3 seconds to load them everytime. So I thought about loading them via jquery. Will this be faster? Is it still safe, my current php looks if a session['loggedin'] variable is 1? Can I do the login in check with jquery too?

Comment: jQuery won't make it any faster or slower. If your server takes 3 seconds, it takes 3 seconds. Period. The only difference will be that the user won't see a page refresh. Your best bet is to take the time to implement the jQuery solution and see if it's more useful *to you*. (It shouldn't take that much time, BTW).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loading a large data set asynchronously will not be faster. In fact it will be slower (more requests).
But doing so might allow you to load smaller chunks of data at a time, and get a more responsive site.

This has nothing to do with jQuery though. jQuery is just a commonly used JavaScript framework that happens to include some nifty ajax-functionality.

As for your sequrity concerns, asynchronous requests are handled by the server just like any other requests, so that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you use ajax you can allow the rest of the page to show so the user is not left with a blank page while the query is done.

Ajax will just call another php script so you can do all the same security checks in that script.

If you are using jquery I would just use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) as it's extremely simple.